# Vectorizing an apply function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply

I have a dataframe  grouped by issue_ids where i want to apply a custom function. The grouped dataframe looks as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
sub_test=pd.DataFrame(columns=['issue_id','step','conversion_rate'],data=[['01-abc-234',0,0.45],['01-abc-234',1,0.35],['01-abc-234',2,0.15],['01-abc-234',3,1],['02-abc-234',0,0.05],['02-abc-234',1,0.15],['02-abc-234',2,0.65],['02-abc-234',3,1]])
sub_test.info()
```

I want to group by issue id and apply the following function for each grouped dataframe

```
def calculate_conversion_step(row, df):
  if row == 0:
      return np.prod(df.loc[df['step'].isin([1, 2]), 'conversion_rate'])
  elif row == 1:
      return np.prod(df.loc[df['step'] == 2, 'conversion_rate'])
  else:
      return 1
```

Basically, what i am doing here is iterating through each dataframe for individual issue ids and applying the aforementioned function to each row of the filtered dataframe. I used .apply() but my dataframe is too large to function well with apply.

```
final=pd.DataFrame()
for issue_id in sub_test['issue_id'].unique():
    int_df = sub_test[sub_test['issue_id'] == issue_id]
    # Apply the 'calculate_conversion_step' function to calculate 'conversion_step' for each issue
    int_df['conversion_step'] = int_df['step'].apply(lambda x: calculate_conversion_step(x, int_df))
    
    # Concatenate the results for each issue
    final = pd.concat([final, int_df])
```

Is there anyway i can make it faster?

this is my expected output[image]

Comment: Please post a sample of sample input dataframes and an example of what your expected output data should look like.

Comment: the question posted has a sample input df, now posting the exapected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
cond0, cond1, cond2 = sub_test['step'].eq(0), sub_test['step'].eq(1), sub_test['step'].eq(2)
s1 = sub_test.groupby('issue_id')['conversion_rate'].transform(lambda x: x.where(cond1 | cond2).prod())
s2 = sub_test.groupby('issue_id')['conversion_rate'].transform(lambda x: x.where(cond2).sum())
sub_test['conversion_step'] = np.select([cond0, cond1], [s1, s2], 1)
```

output:

```
issue_id      step  conversion_rate conversion_step
0   01-abc-234  0   0.45            0.0525
1   01-abc-234  1   0.35            0.1500
2   01-abc-234  2   0.15            1.0000
3   01-abc-234  3   1.00            1.0000
4   02-abc-234  0   0.05            0.0975
5   02-abc-234  1   0.15            0.6500
6   02-abc-234  2   0.65            1.0000
7   02-abc-234  3   1.00            1.0000
```

Comment: could you please add a little about how this works?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sub_test = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['issue_id', 'step', 'conversion_rate'],
    data=[['01-abc-234', 0, 0.45], ['01-abc-234', 1, 0.35], ['01-abc-234', 2, 0.15], 
          ['01-abc-234', 3, 1], ['02-abc-234', 0, 0.05], ['02-abc-234', 1, 0.15], 
          ['02-abc-234', 2, 0.65], ['02-abc-234', 3, 1]]
)

def conversion_step_for_group(df):
    step_1_2_prod = df.loc[df['step'].isin([1, 2]), 'conversion_rate'].prod()
    step_2_prod = df.loc[df['step'] == 2, 'conversion_rate'].prod()
    
    mask_0 = df['step'] == 0
    mask_1 = df['step'] == 1
    mask_else = ~mask_0 & ~mask_1

    df.loc[mask_0, 'conversion_step'] = step_1_2_prod
    df.loc[mask_1, 'conversion_step'] = step_2_prod
    df.loc[mask_else, 'conversion_step'] = 1

    return df

final = sub_test.groupby('issue_id').apply(conversion_step_for_group).reset_index(drop=True)
print(final)
```

Comment: could you please add a little about how this works?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially `cumprod` from bottom up, on just step `0..2`:

```
sub_test['conversion_step'] = (sub_test.query('step <= 2')
    .loc[::-1]
    .groupby(['issue_id'])['conversion_rate']
    .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=1).cumprod())
    .reindex(sub_test.index, fill_value=1)
)
```

Output:

```
     issue_id  step  conversion_rate  conversion_step
0  01-abc-234     0             0.45           0.0525
1  01-abc-234     1             0.35           0.1500
2  01-abc-234     2             0.15           1.0000
3  01-abc-234     3             1.00           1.0000
4  02-abc-234     0             0.05           0.0975
5  02-abc-234     1             0.15           0.6500
6  02-abc-234     2             0.65           1.0000
7  02-abc-234     3             1.00           1.0000
```

Comment: Getting the following erorr with your code-
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'